# Synapse SQL is not working as expected while creating Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I am trying to generate a dynamic SQL.

First I am creating a #TempTable and populating data into the same.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable <---#TempTable has two columns viz. ID int IDENTITY(1,1) and 
                            col_name
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS col_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 
'table_1' AND SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo')
```

Then I running a loop as follows

```
SET @Max_cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable)
SET @Min_cnt = 1
WHILE @Min_cnt < @Max_cnt
set @DySQL_DUP = ' ;WITH Duplicate AS (
            SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY '+ @SourceColNames + ' ORDER BY ' 
  + @SourceColNames + ' ) AS ROW_COUNT FROM 
            dbo.table_1 WHERE FileLoadLogID = 1
            UPDATE dbo.table_1 set 
            col_to_update= ''DUPLICATE_ROWS''
             WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT TARGET.ID FROM dbo.table_1 TARGET
            INNER JOIN Duplicate
            ON TARGET.ID = Duplicate.ID
            WHERE Duplicate.ROW_COUNT >1)
SELECT @DySQL_DUP
```

But this is giving me an error as

```
'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, 
  !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'
```

I am using Synapse SQL. However, The above query is running fine in normal SQL.

Can anyone provide any clue on what I am missing?

Comment: `col_to_update= 'DUPLICATE_ROWS'` is going to return an error before you even get the error you state you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't pass a string value like that inside dynamic SQL... not even in normal SQL honestly
You must put a double single quote around that string value

```
 {...} col_to_update= ''DUPLICATE_ROWS'' {...}
```

Comment: Despite the same I am getting the same error. I have edited the question.

Comment: Hope you found the solution in the meanwhile... you are missing a single quote before `SELECT @DySQL_DUP`. The query itself seems good and I think the error is occurring earlier... even because that SQL string is never executed (not in the code you shared)